# ASP.NET MVC 404 unknown response page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My MVC app returns the following code on 404:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
404
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I have no idea where this response is coming from. I want to make some changes to the page, but this code is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Is your app running in IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix this by adding this to my webconfig:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```